# Is that possible to make or exist a specific page for showing all of labels in google blogger?

Tags: blogger, blogspot

Hi guys I`m beginner in google blogger.

I know it has a gadget for labels wich shows all of labels. but I don`t want a default gadget because it shows every pages of my blog and it takes up too much space. So I wish a specific page for labels like dashboard of my articles.

I'd like to looking for it but I couldn't find it. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

before deleting the "Labels" widget you can copy the link address of the labels that you want to showcase.

Each link have this structure per [label]:

```
your-blog-at-blogspot.com/search/label/[label]?max-results=5
```

Then you can create a "New page" into your blog and with the help of the rich editor customize the appearance for linking each one of the labels that you want to showcase, for example, with links as just text or for example with images or whatever you want as long as it can be done with HTML+Javascript.

Comment: well thanks for you anser but It seems just category and I don't want one of the labels. I needshow all labels on single page anyway thanks